# Can't install pywin32 3.6 build 221

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

I have a machine running windows, and i was trying to install my version of pywin32 (which is the correct one).

The installer recognizes the version of python in the registry. However, when I try to run it, it gives me the following error (image attached)

[image]

Someone asked this question previously, and it was nearly identical to mine; however, there was not a satisfactory answer, which is why I am posing it now.

Thank you!

Comment: Just wanted to let y'all know I also tried running as admin with no sucess.

Comment: Why don't you use pip install method

Comment: ~I'm sure you did, but, did you try running the installer as administrator like the message says?~ And also, just to verify (I know you already said you have the correct installer) maybe triple check that you have the right bitness installer, since you didn't said which bitness you're using. I myself have picked the wrong one once before. Other than that, I can only imagine that maybe the installer is bugged.

Comment: I used the pip install method. Thank you! I'll just leave this up in the meantime though for future reference for others with the same issue